# Scrollwheel Zoom Reversed

Tags: javascript, image, scroll

I found a way to add the scrollwheel zoom in/out for my image, however, I can't seem to find why mine is reversed.  When I'm on the browser or IDE and I scroll down, my scroller goes down.  So I'm curious as to why when I use the scrollwheel on the image they are reversed.  And by reversed I mean when I scroll up it zooms out and when I scroll down it zooms in.  Would anyone have any suggestions for this?  I posted a picture of the code for that area...let me know if you need something else.

Thank you!!
[image: Image of Code]

The actual code:

```
function ScrollZoom(container,max_scale,factor) {
    let target = container.children().first();
    let size = {w:target.width(), h:target.height()};
    let pos = {x:0, y:0};
    let zoom_target = {x:0,y:0};
    let zoom_point = {x:0, y:0};
    let scale = 1;
    target.css('transform-origin','0 0');
    target.on("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", scrolled);

    function scrolled(e) {
        let offset = container.offset();
        zoom_point.x = e.pageX - offset.left;
        zoom_point.y = e.pageY - offset.top;

        e.preventDefault();
        let delta = e.delta || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;
        if(delta === undefined) {
            delta = e.originalEvent.detail;
        }
        delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1,delta));

        zoom_target.x = (zoom_point.x - pos.x)/scale;
        zoom_target.y = (zoom_point.y - pos.y)/scale;

        scale += delta*factor * scale;
        scale = Math.max(1,Math.min(max_scale,scale));

        pos.x = -zoom_target.x * scale + zoom_point.x;
        pos.y = -zoom_target.y * scale + zoom_point.y;

        if(pos.x>0) 
            pos.x = 0;
        if(pos.x+size.w*scale<size.w)
            pos.x = -size.w*(scale-1);
        if(pos.y>0)
            pos.y = 0;
        if(pos.y+size.h*scale<size.h)
            pos.y = -size.h*(scale-1);

        update();
    }

    function update() {
        target.css('transform', 'translate('+(pos.x)+'px,'+(pos.y)+'px) scale('+scale+','+scale+')');
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add a [mcve] with code in the question, without it you're unlikely to get any help.

Comment: Also, please post the code itself, not an image of the code.

Comment: Okay I've posted the code - sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the zooming direction is exactly opposite, it looks like you can just negate `delta` or multiply by `-1` so that a positive delta becomes a negative delta, and a negative delta becomes positive. For example, change this:

```
delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1,delta));
```

...to:

```
delta = -Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, delta));
```

Comment: Omgsh, Jacob (awesome name btw ;) ) you are a life saver!  Thank you so much!